# iPhone won't sync anything to iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud

I'm trying to help my brother transfer his contacts and photos from his old iPhone to his new one. He was using an old iCloud account, I made him a new one, put the same one on both Pphones (one 8 one XS) but nothing will appear on the new iPhone, tried logging in again on both, adding a contact to force it to refresh, but nothing!

I double checked everything is green to sync (especially the contacts he doesn't care about the rest.)

Any ideas?

Edit : It seems that the problem is that all his contact on his old iphone are bound to an old email which wad deleted, can we force sync contacts to his new email ? It doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Syncing is always automatic and it can take several hours.  How long did you wait?  How did you transfer his old iCloud info to his new account?

Comment: He just removed the old icloud, the contact are still on the iphone 8 but won't transfer, we waited overnight, still nothing.

Comment: Have you force restarted both iPhones?

Comment: Yes, new contact that I created appeared on the new iphone, but the old just won't, he doesn't have access to the email associated with the contact group which all his contacts are on... Any way around ? :(

Comment: For clarification, do you mean he knows is old iCloud email address but he doesn't have access to the password?  I'm getting confused by "he doesn't have access to the email associated with the contact group" part of your statement.  Is this a seperate email account, like yahoo or google?

Comment: His contacts are associated with a microsoft exchange account which doesn't exist anymore, they are not associated with his old icloud account.
That's the 'group' they are associated with, sadly